# Why am I getting an uncaught type error when using map in React JS jsx?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs, jsx

I'm creating a component for selecting an input based on available options in my courses object.

I'm currently getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
const SelectInput = ({name, label, onChange, defaultOption, value, error, options}) => {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
            <div className="field">
                {/* Note, value is set here rather than on the option - docs*/}
                <select name={name} value={value} onChange={onChange} className="form-control">
                <option value="">{defaultOption}</option>
                {options.map((option) => {
                    return <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.text}</option>;  
                })}
                </select>
                {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: why do you need to wrap your parameters as an object {} ?

Comment: @BagusTrihatmaja it is object [destraction](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect that `options` are an array but you provide undefined `options` prop, so there is no `map` method for undefined

Provide not undefined options or try this:

```
const SelectInput = ({name, label, onChange, defaultOption, value, error, options = []}) => {
  ...
}
```